# Flatten the Array!

Tags: code-golf, array, ragged-list

In this challenge, your task is to create a program which takes in a nested array and returns a single-dimensional flattened array. For Example `[10,20,[30,[40]],50]` should output `[10,20,30,40,50]`.

---

**Input**

The input will be a nested array (eg. `[10,20,[[[10]]]]`). It will contain only Integers (both negative and positive), Strings and Arrays. You can take the input as function argument, STDIN or whatever suits your language. You can assume that the input array won't have an empty array.

---

**Output**

The output will be a flatted single-dimensional array with the same elements of same type as in the nested array and in the SAME order.

---

**Test Cases**

```
[10,20,30] -> [10,20,30]
[[10]] -> [10]
[["Hi"],[[10]]] -> ["Hi",10]
[[[20],["Hi"],"Hi",20]] -> [20,"Hi","Hi",20]
[[["[]"],"[]"]] -> ["[]","[]"]
```

---

Feel free to ask for any clarification by using comments. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

**Note:** *If your language contains a built-in for this, then you must NOT use it.*

---

**Edit**

Please also include a link to a website where your code can be executed.

Comment: Some languages treat strings as arrays, is [["Hi"],[[10]]] -> ["H","i",10] ok?

Comment: @NᴮᶻNo, I'm afraid that isn't OK.

Comment: I'm really surprised this isn't a duplicate

Comment: @Mego I was surprised too to find out that there was an `unflatten` question but no `flatten` question on PPCG.

Comment: Is it okay if the output is an array of all strings, but still contain the same values in the same order as the input array? For instance, is it okay if the input `[[[20],["Hi"],"Hi",20]]` results in the output `['20', "'Hi'", "'Hi'", '20']`?

Comment: What if your language only supports subarrays of the same size? (E.g. Java?) What if the type of each element must be the same? (E.g. Java, C++ etc.?) Also, please add e.g. `["[",[["[",],'[',"['['"]]` as a test case.

Comment: @flawr That test case only makes sense for languages that support bot `'` and `"` as delimiters. (But I agree that a test case involving `[`, `]`, `"` and ``\`` inside a string would be useful.)

Comment: The test cases also exclude languages which do not support these kinds of arrays with multiple types, or with another notation for array literals.

Comment: @R.Kap Sorry but that's not allowed. I've edited the question also.

Comment: @flawr Of course, but I think we always assume that  you just rewrite the test cases with your language's syntax. Making using of something like redundant literal syntax that is only present in some languages seems unnecessarily specific.

Comment: @flawr Java can have subarrays of different sizes (but not different types, thus not different 'depths').

Comment: @DavidConrad not true - an array is an `Object`, so an `Object[]` can contain other arbitrary `Object[]`. Obviously this isn't typesafe, and any algorithm flattening an `Object[]` would need to use reflection to work out what's going on.

Comment: In C or asm (where polymorphic data types have to be implemented manually), I'm imagining accepting the multi-dimensional array in serialized form.  i.e. treat the problem as a text-processing problem, just removing the internal unquoted `[` and `]` characters :P

Comment: If your chosen language can't handle nested arrays, why are you worrying about using it for this challenge? It obviously can't do this challenge, which is fine. On a side note, using `Object[]` in Java and `std::any[]` in C++17 (or the equivalent `boost::any` in earlier C++ versions) would work.

Comment: What if the language automatically flattens the input?

Comment: Requiring support for both numbers and strings just makes this challenge unnecessarily complicated, and deviates from the core task.

Comment: A test case like `["1",[2]]` would probably be good.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## K, 3 bytes

```
,//
```

This is a fairly common idiom. "Join over converge".

[try it here with oK](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html?run=%20%2C%2F%2F%281%3B%282%3B3%3B%284%3B5%29%29%29).

How it works:

Join (`,`) fuses together atoms or lists to produce a list. Over (`/`) takes a verb (in this case join) and applies it between each element of a list, left to right. Thus, the compound `,/` will flatten all the top level elements of the list. The symbol `/` actually has different meanings depending on the valence (number of arguments) of the verb with which it is compounded. When we provide `,/` as the verb, the final `/` acts as "converge"- it repeatedly applies `,/` to the input until it stops changing. Some other languages call a feature like this a "fixed point combinator". By repeatedly fusing bottom level lists, you will eventually arrive at a single flat list, and none of the operations will perturb the order of elements. This seems to solve the problem.

Comment: All right, thanks for the explanation! Have your well-earned +1.

Comment: [a similar solution to a different problem](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71476/determine-the-depth-of-an-array/71494#71494).

Comment: I came up with the same algorithm (but not in this language). +1 for picking the right language to implement it in!

Comment: @Cyoce If your language has equivalents to the three operators used here, it's an extremely natural solution. By all means post your variation.

Comment: @JohnE Long story, I'm deriving a language from algorithms I come up with, so the language isn't finished (and thus implemented) yet.

Comment: gorgeous, marvelous!

Answer (score 39):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

Inspired by [@user81655's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80102/7588):

```
f=a=>a.map?[].concat(...a.map(f)):a
```

Comment: Very clever! +1 for [ab]using JS's weird way of handling missing keys!

Comment: I can beat that.

Comment: @BaldBantha: We're looking forward for your answer :-)

Comment: Crap NVM My 33 byte solution fails on one of the test cases. NOOOO

Comment: @Bergi here it is anyway: `i=x=>x.join().split(',');`

Comment: Nevermind again! your answer does the same thing as mine! brb answering.

Comment: @BaldBantha, join-split will fail on commas inside of strings.

Answer (score 19):

### Mathematica, <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
{##&@@#&//@#}&
```

An unnamed function which takes and returns a list, e.g.:

```
{##&@@#&//@#}& @ {{{20}, {"Hi"}, "Hi", 20}}
(* {20, "Hi", "Hi", 20} *)
```

#### Explanation

Syntactic sugar party!

To understand how this works, note that every expression in Mathematica is either an atom (e.g. numbers, strings, symbols) or a compound expression of the form `f[a, b, c, ...]`, where `f`, `a`, `b`, `c` are themselves arbitrary expressions. Here, `f` is called the *head* of the expression. Everything else on top of that is just syntactic sugar. E.g. `{a, b, c}` is just `List[a, b, c]`.

We start with `//@` which maps a functions over *all* levels of a list. For instance:

```
f //@ {{{20}, {"Hi"}, "Hi", 20}}
(* f[{f[{f[{f[20]}], f[{f["Hi"]}], f["Hi"], f[20]}]}] *)
```

Note that this maps `f` over atoms as well as compound expressions. What we're now looking for is a way to get rid of the list heads and keep everything else.

The `Apply` function is normally used to feed the elements of a list as separate arguments to a function, but its actual definition is more general and simply replaces the head of an expression. E.g. `Apply[g, f[a, b]]` gives `g[a, b]`.

Now there's a special "head" called `Sequence` that simply vanishes. E.g. `{a, Sequence[b, c], d}` just evaluates to `{a, b, c, d}`. The idea for flattening the list is to replace the heads of all inner lists with `Sequence` so that they get splatted into their surrounding list. So what we want is to `Apply` the head `Sequence` to the lists. Conveniently if we `Apply` something to an atom, it just leaves the atom unchanged, so we don't have to distinguish between types of expressions at all.

Finally, there's one small issue: `f` is also applied to the outermost level, so that it also removes the outermost `List`, which we don't want. The shortest way to counter that is simply to wrap the result in a list again, such that the surrounding `Sequence` can safely vanish.

Note that there's neither `Apply` nor `Sequence` in the code. `@@` is an operator form of `Apply` and `##&` is a standard golfing trick to shorten the long built-in name `Sequence`. So ungolfing everything a bit, we get something like:

```
flatten[list_] := { MapAll[Apply[Sequence], list] }
```

For more details on how and why the `##&` works, see the section on "Sequences of arguments" [in my answer for the Mathematica tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45188/8478).

Comment: First time I've seen `//@`.  Very useful to know about!

Comment: `//@` captures a neat pattern. Reminds me a bit of some of the recursive combinators in Joy. Do you have a link to a good reference to any related functions in Mathematica? I'm very interested in ways of factoring explicit recursion out of programs.

Comment: @JohnE Well, [here's the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAll.html). You could also look at things like `Map`, `MapAt`, `Apply`, as well as `Replace` and related functions. In general though there's a lot of function which take an optional *levelspec* parameter (see my original 16-byte solution), which lets you apply the function at multiple/all levels at once.

Answer (score 13):

### Python 2, 43 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:[l]*(l*0!=[])or sum(map(f,l),[])
```

On a list, recurses on the elements and concatenates the results. On a string or number, encases in a singleton list.

Unfortunately, Python 2's ordering for types `int < list < string` sandwiches `list` between the others, requiring two inequalities to check. So, instead, `l*0` is checked against the empty list `[]`, otherwise giving `0` or `""`.

Comment: `f=lambda s:[s]["">s>f:]or sum(map(f,s),[])` saves 1.

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby, <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 34 bytes

Recursive solution. Now with exception handling! (might as well credit @akostadinov for inspiring the change though)

```
f=->a{a.map(&f).inject:+rescue[a]}
```

[IDEOne link](http://ideone.com/Om3WAT)

Comment: kudos for shortness, awesome

Comment: I didn't know you could use `rescue` like that

Comment: @Cyoce I think it's because Ruby technically doesn't have a `try` block, so you use `begin` instead to differentiate the parts you want to be catching for and the parts that you don't. So since you're catching for the entire rest of the block before it, you technically don't need it? The rest is just trimmed whitespace, since Ruby interprets the line as `...inject(:+) rescue [a]`

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny, no, rescue on same line is different, just rescuing that line. e.g. `a = raise("haha") rescue 1` would assign `1` to `a`. It'

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny There's an inline `rescue`, like there's an inline `if` and `while`.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

```js
f=a=>[].concat(...a.map(v=>v.pop?f(v):v))
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="6" cols="40">[[[20],["Hi"],"Hi",20]]</textarea><br /><button onclick="result.textContent=JSON.stringify(f(eval(input.value)))">Go</button><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 24 bytes

```perl6
{gather {$_».&{.take}}}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{ # has $_ as an implicit parameter

  gather {

    $_\ # the parameter from the outer block
    »\  # for each single value in the structure
    .&( # call the following block as if it was a method
      { # this block has its own $_ for a parameter
        .take # call the .take method implicitly on $_
      }
    )
  }
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6

use v6.c;
use Test;

my &flatten = {gather {$_».&{.take}}}

my @tests = (
  [10,20,30], [10,20,30],
  [[10,],], [10,],
  [["Hi",],[[10,],],], ["Hi",10],
  [[["[]",],"[]"],], ["[]","[]"],
);

plan @tests / 2;

for @tests -> $input, $expected {
  # is-deeply cares about the exact type of its inputs
  # so we have to coerce the Seq into an Array
  is-deeply flatten($input).Array, $expected, $input.perl;
}
```

```
1..4
ok 1 - $[10, 20, 30]
ok 2 - $[[10],]
ok 3 - $[["Hi"], [[10],]]
ok 4 - $[[["[]"], "[]"],]
```

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, 43 bytes

```
data D a=L a|N[D a]
f(L x)=[x]
f(N l)=f=<<l
```

Haskell has neither nested lists with different depths of the sublists nor mixed types for the list elements. For nesting I define a custom data type `D` which is either a leaf `L` that holds some element or a node `N` which is a list of `D`s. For the mixed elements I use the predefined data type `Either` which combines two types into one, here `Either String Integer`. The new type `D` and the flatten function `f` are fully polymorphic in the type of the leaf elements, so I don't have to take extra care of anything regarding `Either`.

Usage example: `f (N[N[L(Right 20)], N[L(Left "Hi")], L(Left "Hi") , L(Right 20)])` -> `[Right 20,Left "Hi",Left "Hi",Right 20]`.

Answer (score 6):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 43 bytes

```
f=a=>a.map?[for(b of a)for(c of f(b))c]:[a]
```

Just because I could even avoid using `concat`.

Comment: Isn't it _ECMAScript 6_ not _Firefox 30+_?

Comment: @SolomonUcko No, `[for(of)]` is only available in Firefox 30+. It was proposed for ES7 but later dropped.

Comment: thanks for explaining! Mostly, i just thought it was `for(__ in __)`

Comment: @SolomonUcko [for(in)] was an alternative experimental syntax which gave you the keys of the object.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
us+]Y
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=us%2B]Y&input=[[[20]%2C[%22Hi%22]%2C%22Hi%22%2C20]]&test_suite_input=[10%2C20%2C30]%0A[[10]]%0A[[%22Hi%22]%2C[[10]]]%0A[[[20]%2C[%22Hi%22]%2C%22Hi%22%2C20]]%0A[[[%22[]%22]%2C%22[]%22]]&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=us%2B]Y&input=[[[20]%2C[%22Hi%22]%2C%22Hi%22%2C20]]&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=[10%2C20%2C30]%0A[[10]]%0A[[%22Hi%22]%2C[[10]]]%0A[[[20]%2C[%22Hi%22]%2C%22Hi%22%2C20]]%0A[[[%22[]%22]%2C%22[]%22]]&debug=0)

But of course, there is also a build-in function, that handles the task in just 2 bytes: `.n` ([Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.n&input=[[[20]%2C[%22Hi%22]%2C%22Hi%22%2C20]]&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=[10%2C20%2C30]%0A[[10]]%0A[[%22Hi%22]%2C[[10]]]%0A[[[20]%2C[%22Hi%22]%2C%22Hi%22%2C20]]%0A[[[%22[]%22]%2C%22[]%22]]&debug=0))

Comment: Just 3 away from the current winner! +1

Comment: @Sting: Golfed away another byte.  Forgot that Pyth append the last character `G` implicitly,  if I don't write it.

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>34</s> 29 bytes

Functions.

If needs to flatten to list like `my @a = f(@a)`, 29 bytes:

```
sub f{map{ref()?f(@$_):$_}@_}
```

[Test it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/hlPjyf)

If needs to flatten to array ref like `my $a = f($a)`, 34 bytes:

```
sub f{[map{ref()?@{f(@$_)}:$_}@_]}
```

[Test it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/V8Xg0Q).

## Perl 5.22.0+, 27 bytes

Thanks to [hobbs](/u/1683).

If needs to flatten to list like `my @a = f(@a)`, 27 bytes:

```
sub f{map{ref?f(@$_):$_}@_}
```

[Test it on JDoodle](https://jdoodle.com/a/Rp)

If needs to flatten to array ref like `my $a = f($a)`, 32 bytes:

```
sub f{[map{ref?@{f(@$_)}:$_}@_]}
```

[Test it on JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/Ro).

Comment: I haven't tested it, but think `?@{f@$_}:` should work instead of `?@{f(@$_)}:`, saving two bytes.

Comment: @msh210 No, it’s not working. The compiler doesn’t khow that `f` is a function because `f` not yet declared. `sub f{}sub f{... f@$_ ...}` working.

Comment: 1. `ref` doesn't need the parens to work, saving 2 bytes. 2. As far as I can see, `sub f{map{ref?f(@$_):$_}@_}` is within the rules and saves another 5. `f` takes an array (nonref) as a list, so it can return the same.

Comment: @hobbs 1. If no parentheses with `ref` then the compiler assumes that `?` is starting `?PATTERN?` operation like `ref(?PATTERN?)`. So the compiler searches second `?` and throws error.

Comment: @DenisIbaev ah. `?PATTERN?` was removed in 5.22.0 (`m?PATTERN?` still works) and I'm testing on a recent version. So you can gain those two bytes by specifying 5.22+.

Comment: @hobbs 2. I thought about it. But I wasn’t sure that it’s within the rules.

Comment: @hobbs Thanks. I added all versions.

Answer (score 5):

### Julia, 29 bytes

```
f(x,y=vcat(x...))=x==y?x:f(y)
```

This is recursive splatting into a concatenate function until a reaching a fix point. Example

```
julia> f([1,[2,[3,[4,[5,[6]]]]]])
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 14 bytes

```
{Reap[Sow@>_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xC8IwEIX3/IpQHFQixFYXwSK4OImo23FIqal20WICDuJvj3eNKUUMNNx97@X1Fc4V5dX4Si6W/rU3RQOH@3OVn/Dth2MJU61SrTKNcpL3NgE0Y4S8Jps6QRVw4ExUECHVpAVLi9P4mOJaECmbE0D28f1NojHsYjwSYmvM2cKgacoLit2jvrmjsW5dWGOhUhKEpMNdJaVLaqsCabvF@W@lTuxXUF0exUFG34ytc/2jAP@JJFYEov8A)

Fortunately, Attache has a "vectorization" operator, which applies a function at the atoms of a list. In this case, all we need to do is to set up a reaper with `Reap` and `Sow` all atoms of the input `_` with `@>`. I think it's quite elegant.

### Alternatives

**15 bytes:** `` Fixpoint{`'^^_} ``

**16 bytes:** `Fixpoint!&Concat`

**17 bytes:** `{q:=[]q&Push@>_q}`

**17 bytes:** `Fixpoint[&Concat]`

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), 30 bytes

```
1>`("(\\.|[^"])+")|[][]
$1
$
]
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAoxPmAoIihcXC58W14iXSkrIil8W11bXQokMQokCl0&input=WzEwLDIwLDMwXQpbWzEwXV0KW1siSGkiXSxbWzEwXV1dCltbWzIwXSxbIkhpIl0sIkhpIiwyMF1dCltbWzIwXSxbIkhbXVwiW11pIl0sIkhcXFwiW11pIiwyMF1d) (The first line is only used to run multiple test cases at once.)

Retina has no concept of arrays, string literals or numbers, so I decided to go with a "common" input format of `[...,...]` style arrays and `"`-delimited strings, where `\` can be used inside the strings to escape any character (in particular `"` and `\` itself).

The program itself simply matches either a full string or a square bracket, and replaces them with `$1` which keeps strings and removes square brackets. The limit `1>` skips the first match so that we don't remove the leading `[`. However, this does remove the trailing `]`, so we add it back in in a separate stage.

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 11 bytes

```
.F~]+=])K~]
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=.F~%5D%2B%3D%5D%29K~%5D&input=%5B%5B%5B20%5D%2C%5B%22Hi%22%5D%2C%22Hi%22%2C20%5D%5D)

Explanation:

```
.F~]+=])    - Deep for loop
  ~]        -    contents of `]` ([] by default)
    +       -  ^+i
     =]     - `]` = ^
        K~] - Output value
        K   - Remove the output from the for loop
         ~] - Return the contents of `]`
```

#### Or 7 bytes after a bugfix

```
M?+]K~]
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=M%3F%2B%5DK~%5D&input=%5B%5B%5B20%5D%2C%5B%22Hi%22%5D%2C%22Hi%22%2C20%5D%5D)

Explanation:

```
M?+]    - Deep map
 ?+]    -  `]` = `]`+i
    K~] - Output value
    K   - Remove the output from the for loop
     ~] - Return the contents of `]`
```

#### Or even 2 bytes if printing to stdout is allowed (This might come under built-ins)

```
M
<newline required>
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=M%0A&input=%5B%5B%5B20%5D%2C%5B%22Hi%22%5D%2C%22Hi%22%2C20%5D%5D)

This deeply applies the `print_newline` function to every non-sequence item in the input and recurses for sequence items.

Comment: Just 4 away from K! +1

Answer (score 3):

## Java (v8) <strike>390</strike> 276 bytes

```
public static Object[] f(final Object[]a) {
    List<Object>r=new ArrayList<>();boolean t=false;int n=0;
    for(final Object p:a)
        if(t=p instanceof Object[]){for(final Object q:(Object[])p) r.add(q);}
        else r.add(p);
    return(t)?f(r.toArray()):r.toArray();
}
```

Just for completeness and all that. :) Can't say Java's code-efficient.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This question is [tag:code-golf], so please try to minimize your code. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any specific suggestions? I have minimized it, Java is just a heavy language.

Comment: Remove all the unnecessary spaces, tabs, and newlines. Change `oaf` to `o`, and change `flatten` to `f`.

Comment: You don't need the `final`s, the whole thing can be a lambda, you don't need `public static`...

Comment: you could save couple characters if you use generics instead object

Comment: you could also save 2 bytes if you replace `false` with `1>2`, and additional 2 bytes you could get if you declare n but not define (compiler automatically define it as 0)

Comment: @user902383 I don't think you understand generics, but yes in this case I suppose that 'Object' is implied by no specified type.

Comment: @David Conrad May Lambas are 'eww' in most cases. And yes I could drop the finals and strictly speaking I don't need the keywords. At the end of the day though, there's no point in changes that squeeze out less than maybe 20 bytes because Java isn't (generally speaking) an interpreted language. There's no way it will ever compete with half the languages people chose to use.

Comment: It has nothing to do with interpreted languages. This is *code golf*. And, no, lambdas are not 'eww'.

Comment: Look, don't play stupid. 'Eww' is a matter of opinion as are many opinions about what is good or bad code and I do in fact have a negative opinion of lambdas/anonymous functions and prefer to avoid using them when I can.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 57 bytes

```py
f=lambda a:sum([list==type(x)and f(x)or[x]for x in a],[])
```

Try it online: [Python 2](http://ideone.com/fork/vHoqK3), [Python 3](http://ideone.com/fork/cFnU0B)

Thanks to Kevin Lau for the `list==type(x)` trick.

Comment: `type(x)==list` is shorter than `isinstance(x,list)`.

Comment: *“It will contain only Integers (both negative and positive), Strings and Arrays.”* How about ``[`x`>'['and...``? (That works in Python 2 only.)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby

there is builtin `flatten` method.

You can run here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php

One 43 bytes, but thought to share:

```
f=->a{a.inject([]){|r,e|r+(f[e]rescue[e])}}
```

One 45 bytes that is more efficient than the previous and the other ruby answer:

```
f=->a{a.map{|e|Array===e ?f[e]:[e]}.inject:+}
```

here's benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'
n=10^9
arr=[[[20],[[[[[[[[123]]]]]]]],"ads",[[[[[[[4]]]]]]],5,[[[[[[[[[[6]]]]]]]]]],7,8,[[[[[[[[[[9]]]]]]]]]],[[[[[[[[[[0]]]]]]]]]],[[[[[[[[[[[["Hi"]]]]]]]]]]]],[[[[[["Hi"]]]]]],[[[[[20]]]]]]]
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { f=->a{a.map(&f).inject:+rescue[a]}; f[arr] }
  x.report { f=->a{a.map{|e|e!=[*e]?[e]:f[e]}.inject:+}; f[arr] }
  x.report { f=->a{a.inject([]){|r,e|r+(f[e]rescue[e])}}; f[arr] }
  x.report { f=->a{a.map{|e|Array===e ?f[e]:[e]}.inject:+}; f[arr] }
end
```

result:

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.000432)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000303)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000486)
   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000228)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! Unfortunately, your answer is not valid, because of this rule: `Note: If your language contains a built-in for this, then you must NOT use it`.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere, thanks, didn't know that

Comment: How does my new update stack against time-wise against yours? Also, just like my new answer, you can remove the spaces around `rescue`

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny updated, thanks! `rescue` looks to be rather slow btw, like `try/catch` in java

Comment: Update your bytecount, too

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny, updated, also altered the faster solution by your example `map.reduce` and it became shorter and a little faster

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>39</s> 34 + 1 (`-p` flag) 35 bytes

Oneliner. Inspired by [Martin Büttner](/a/80109/34575).

```
#!perl -p
s/("(\\.|[^"])+"|]$|^\[)|[][]/$1/g
```

[Test it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/sBPlDe).

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 68 bytes

```
(def f #(if(some vector? %)(f(mapcat(fn[z](if(vector? z)z[z]))%))%))
```

`mapcat` first applies function to each element and then concats results. So every time it concats one 'nesting level' is lost. Concat does not work on not sequences so elements have to be wrapped into vector if they're not vector.

You can try it here: http://www.tryclj.com

```
(f [[[20],["Hi"],"Hi",20]])
(f [[["[]"],"[]"]])
```

Comment: Nice first code-golf. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

## ANSI C, 193 bytes

```
#define b break;
#define c case
#define p putch(_);
char f;main(_){switch(_){c 1:putch(91);b c 34:f^=1;p b c 91:f&&p b c 93:f&&p b c 10:c 13:putch(93);return;default:p}_=getch();main(_);}
```

:-/, any suggestions? Btw, I did try to find an online source to compile this but the WL is strict for this code to compile. It will work for VS and gcc otherwise.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first golf. Good luck ahead!

Comment: Thanks! It was an attempt to up my points so that I can get commenting privileges elsewhere. It appears things don't work like that the accounts are for different portals. :D I will see if some nifty features from c++ can be used.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript 20 bytes

```
a=>(a+[]).split(',')
```

The array + array is equal to array.toString

Comment: @WheatWizard thanks for the welcome and I am new to the site. actually `a` is an argument of the function. I will try to edit out the function now.

Comment: I think now it's ok @WheatWizard. Please let me know if there is a problem with this

Comment: Actually looking at the javaScript docs an anonymous function would *definitely* be shorter, you would only have to add `a=>` to the beginning of your code.

Comment: @WheatWizard I updated with the arrow function as you mentioned. But I have to remove the snippet because arrow function doesn't support direct invoke. It is only for callbacks

Comment: Save 2 bytes with `split\`,\``

Comment: This doesn't handle strings with commas in them correctly

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) + [free](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1.7/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html), 7 bytes

In order to represent a ragged list in Haskell we use a free monad of lists.  Luckily for us provided with the free monad is `retract`, which does a lot of different things, but when given the particular type here it flattens the free monad of lists down to a single list.

```haskell
retract
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHBatwwEIbvfoqB5GBDbGdbSulS@9ImEEiXUnIrIQy2ZIu1JCPJdEPaZ9@OLK26S0/W/P/MfDPjEe2eTdPxrbyCR1TDggODH6j2u6fXmVm4Kv9kZQlfGRdKOKGVhU7PgvXAjZbgRgZWL6ZjoPkaccMYSN0vE721AcesE2rwTUbnZrut6xG7PWGqMbArbYZ6Dlrty8sP1ab6WPe6s7U1Xf1FK2f0VH3TCvvqnjKq0ckp69Eh@BA4YAbQwPfFsPX5O@g5h/yUUBRZJpR1qGjY@0V1jqbj0LQpiKkF/BqZYdSFS5x9Cgw6aeCDPICKxMw9ILmhD9lNHIPEz9etlyjHn/ph9/iwuwsAf@LMMGewc7DdwrpmnCzODmW77njKSvyG@pG4GHXurmVog40W2raBaNINHDMec3GCPEKoZXmJxVDwcsY8afMoIkt6dQ2T4feVdHKup37NSZvJANQGpwkOUBHp4EkSDv/RJbFSh5eLu6e1k8/PN/cdwub//CNv4hmOEoWipF7ThWYjlIPrVP9zpWxuwq99F7/vb@DMPamf4ndz@/xcHP8C)

But we can also make our own solution using other tools, like `foldFree`:

## 11 bytes

```haskell
foldFree id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHBatwwEIbvfoqB5GBDbGdbSulS@9ImEEiXUnIrIQy2ZIu1JCPJdEPaZ9@OLK26S0/S/P9ovpnRiHbPpun4Vl7BI6phwYHBD1T73dPrzCxclX@ysoSvjAslnNDKQqdnwXrgRktwIwOrF9Mx0HyNuGEMpO6Xie7agGPWCTX4IqNzs93W9YjdnjDVGNiVNkM9B632z8sP1ab6WPe6s7U1Xf1FK2f0VH3TCvvqnjKq0ckp69Eh@BA4YAbQwPfFsPX6O@g5h/yUUBRZJpR1qKjZ@0V1jrrj0LQpiKkF/BqZYVSFS5x9Cgw6aeCDPICKxMw9ILmhDtlNbIPEz9etlyjHr/ph9/iwuwsAv@LMMGewc7Ddwjpm7Cz2DmW7znjKSvyG6pG4GHXurs/QBhsttG0D0aQdOGY85mIFeYRQyfISi@HByxnzpM2jiCzp1TVMhp9X0sq5nvo1J00mA1AbnCY4QEWkgydJOPxHl8RKFV4u9p7GTj4/n9xXCJP/84@8SYHojxKFosRe05ZmI5SD61Tj50ra3ITvfRfP9zdw5p7UT/Hc3D4/F8e/)

However `foldFree` basically is just a more general version of `retract`, and we can do it without it:

## 21 bytes

```haskell
iter(>>=id).fmap(:[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFRa9swEMff/SkOmgcbanlZGWNh9su2QKELZewtlCJsyRaxJCPJLKXrZ09PlqIl7Mm6/939f3fngdoDG8fTa3kDD1T1M@0Z/KLqsPv9MjELN@VbVpbwnXGhhBNaWWj1JFgH3GgJbmBg9WxaBpovETeMgdTdPOJbG3DMOqF6bzI4N9lNVQ20PSCGDIFNtOmrKWiVby8/kTX5XHW6tZU1bfVNK2f0SH5qRTuyxQoyODlmHXUUfAgcaAZQw@Ns2PL8G/ScQ34uKIosE8o6qnDY7axah9NxqJsUxNIC/gzMMHThkk6@BHqdNPBBHkBFYuYekLLBB9N1HAPFr6vGS1jjT32/e7jf/QgAf@LMMGdo62CzgWXNOFmcHcpm2fFclfg1@qE4G3WZXdqoDWlqoWlqiEm8gWPGY65OkEcIWpbXWBoani@YZ20aRGRJry5hSvh9JZ6c67FbatJmMgC1oeMIRyBIOnqShON/dIms5PB8dfe0dsrzy829Q9j8X/7Eaz9fjqroCuKvn2/2T8VJUqGwpdN4r8kI5WCV3PYLc30bfvTH@L27hYvsWf0Sv@sPT@j6Dg)

If we want to use *none* of the functions provided by free just the definition of the monad and prelude functions we can do:

## 29 bytes

```haskell
f(Pure a)=[a]
f(Free a)=a>>=f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHBatwwEL37KwaSgw2xnW0ppUvsS5tAIF1K6S0sYbAl26wlGUmmG9J@@3ZkyeouOVnz3pv3ZsY9mgMbx9NbfgVPKLsZOwY/UR52v14nZuAq/5vkOXxjfJCDHZQ00KhpYC1wrQTYnoFRs24YKL5UXDMGQrXzSG@lwTJjB9k5k97ayWzLssfmQDFF77MLpbty8ljp2vNPxab4XLaqMaXRTflVSavVWHxXEtvigRRFb8WYtGgRXAkcMAGo4Mes2fL84/GUQ7oKsixJBmksShr2YZaNpek4VHUsgjSD3z3TjFy4wMlJoFMRA1ekPiiLmakLiKz3IboKYxB4d107iDTu1I@7p8fdvQ9wJ040sxobC9stLGuGycLskNfLjqsq5lfkR@Cs5Tm7tKHxNBqo6woCSTewTLuYixOkIYQs88tY9A0vZ5krNvVDyBIOXcpIuH0FnZyrsV00cTPhA5XGcYQjFJR0dEkCju/SBWVFh5eLu8e1I8/PN3cOfvP//ImvBtUz7hMe5FmFpOMngYOkxlbR1SY9SAvX0fN5adzc@N/9IXw/3sAZu6Jfwndzu99np38)

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 63 bytes

```rkt
(define(f l)(apply append(map(λ(x)(if(list? x)(f x)`(,x)))l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 17 Bytes

```
a=>eval(`[${a}]`)
```

Finally, JavaScript's type conversions can be put to some good use! Please note that this will actually output an array, but string conversion (putting it into HTML) causes it to become a comma separated list.

If comma separated lists are acceptable output, then the following is valid:

## 7 Bytes

```
a=>""+a
```

NOTE: Snippet is broken for some reason

```js
var subject = 
  a=>eval(`[${a}]`)
```

```html
<input oninput="try {output.innerHTML = subject(this.value)} catch(e) {output.innerHTML='Invaild Input'}" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when run in the console for input `["["]`... I tried running `(a=>eval(`[${a}]`))(["["])` and got a `SyntaxError`

Comment: @jrich. You just get this error when you type character by character. If you copy and paste any _valid_ array, it will work as expected. By the way, nice answer SpeedNinja, I would only change `oninput` event with a `button` click.

Comment: This doesn't work for strings with commas in them

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8 165 chars

```
import java.util.*;<T>T[]f(T[]a){List<T>l=new ArrayList<>();for(T e:a)if(e instanceof Object[])Collections.addAll(l,f((T[])e));else l.add(e);return(T[])l.toArray();}
```

Ungolfed into a class:

```
public class Q80096 {

    public static <T> T[] flatten(T[] array) {
        List<T> flattenedList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T element : array)
            if (element instanceof Object[])
                 Collections.addAll(flattenedList, flatten((T[]) element));
            else
                flattenedList.add(element);
        return (T[]) flattenedList.toArray();
    }
}
```

This answer is based on [Jeremy Harton's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80156/52713). I used it changed it in some places and created a more golf-like version.

Comment: would it be not better when using Arrays.asList() on "array" and then go the foreach with lambda and end this with a Collector?

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 73 Bytes

```
<?array_walk_recursive($_GET,function($i)use(&$r){$r[]=$i;});print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 66 bytes

```cs
T[]f<T>(T[]a)=>a.SelectMany(x=>x is T[]y?f(y):new[]{x}).ToArray();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/JDo2zSbETgNIJ2ra2iXqBafmpCaX@CbmVWpU2NpVKGQWKwDlKu3TNCo1rfJSy6NjqytqNfVC8h2LihIrNTSt/wcUZeaVaKRpACUV8pOygLqBagwNdIwMdIwNajU1rbmwqsCunEj1Sh6eSrU6aEYQqxmFY2SAZg7Y6FodEAV0EzlGKkXHAh0HJkHa/wMA)

Recursive function that takes an `object[]` as input. Yes, there is a type parameter, so you *could* pass an array of any type... But it only works correctly if all nested arrays are of the same type. That is a requirement that I have added :)

It would be more flexible to get this to work with an input of type `IList` or `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 74 bytes

```
def d(l)do l|>Stream.flat_map(fn x->if is_list(x)do d(x)else[x]end end)end
```

First Elixir answer, so can probably be golfed a bit.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY69CsMgFEb3PoU4KVix6d6t0E4tdBQJglos/gQ14NB3T5VkLhm@78LlHO7VzlabFqWNj2p2GjxTfCfpgYp9CRRyWEXgvpdXSVp6apwso5cTMgHU48UaYPPobC6odlC1oV3WvAodFGjBLUvL4f6g01wyuIbZ00@0AW23qEL8xMjAyJkJTCCB@D/caLEPhDcLBVmFfQYfWBNWr3d7a68JuehS781Yfg)

**Explanation:**

```python
def d(l)do l|>            # Recursive method taking a list as input:
  Stream.flat_map(fn x->  #  Map over each item `x` of the input-list:
    if is_list(x)do       #   If `x` is a list itself:
      d(x)                #    Do a recursive call with `x`
    else                  #   Else:
      [x]                 #    Simply leave `x` unchanged
    end                   #   End of the if-else statements
  end)                    #  End of the map
end                       # End of the recursive method
```

Of course, if builtins were allowed, this could have been **25 bytes** instead:

```python
fn(l)->List.flatten(l)end
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jc/NCgIhFAXg/TzFxZWCiU3r2gUTBLUXFwNqGP6Eo9DbmzK0jGlzFpfvwLna2bdNVWnjoypOwz3FR5o9qDgAmGM1ATuyO13tkplxc866H3RQFeByY6@SFziH4tkz2oANw2LP6cjpgUtCEUVk@OUalJsGTRZJutpNLEbe7Frp2Xb8UUJCdt/zi/t7Hw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
;/ÐL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99a//AEn////0cbGugYGehEGwOxiUFsrI6pQSwA)

### Explanation

```
;/   | Reduce by concatenation
  ÐL | Loop until no further changes
```

Built-in `F` would be one byte if allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
#~Level~{-1}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7876Zg@1@5zie1LDWnrlrXsFbtf0BRZl6Jg5abgr4DV3W1oYGOkYGOsUGtjgKIUwumlTwylWp1IHywQLURUAFUGEQC9UAllKprQWIgsrb2PwA)

Un-golfed: `F[x_] := Level[x, {-1}]`

picks out the elements of the structure at the last level of its [tree form](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeForm.html). I'm not sure this counts as "avoiding the builtin" (which would be [`Flatten`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)).

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
ċ↰ᵐc|g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpnRrpbpspYe7Oh81NdY@3Drh/5FuoASQkVyT/v9/tEK0oYGOkYGOsUGsTjSQHQuilDwylWBcEB1tBJKFiIJIoAaIuFJ0LEgIRMYqxAIA)

```
ċ         The input is a list,
    |     and the output is
   c      the concatenation of
 ↰ᵐ       the results of this predicate on the list's elements.
    |     If the input is not a list, then it
     g    wrapped in a list is the output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nial](https://github.com/danlm/QNial7), 27 bytes

```
DOWN[simple,pass,pass,link]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8tMzPnvppBZrPDfxT/cL7o4M7cgJ1WnILG4GELkZOZlx/635iovyixJVXBTiI6ONjKI1YlW98hUj9UBkTpAfux/QwUjBWMA)

strangely interesting in nial since it doesn't have fixpoint.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 123 bytes

```
function f(a)o,t={},function(s)for _,v in next,s do if type(v)=="table"then t(v)else o[#o+1]=v end end end t(a)return o end
```

I'm sure this is not the best answer, but I thought I'd post it since nobody has given a Lua solution yet. Suggestions welcome!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BTsMwFETX7SlGZmMLB6VhHdbcoaqQSR1qiOzI/kmJopw92GkLlWgX9mJm3p9pOjXPdWcrMs6i5ko4SeU4yYvGg6idx5vsYSys/iYZsHcwNWhoNe9FWTJS741mdNAWFBXdBA23fXCPm13ZQ9v976PY4DV13sIlYc4yLPRT5WylCJ9dILiO2o4ClIXyXg3gzjYDjs5/BaQ5dROjixUEjoYOUPgwfewPulVekfPrdeuNJX59ndfjJpdFLp/zSYJJJgRWKyDLXnAxbmORm24gd8Ls1bBJnqA/6gQlT94lxyIuO/NLsrjqTXjcuOhn894Ztt2lC@n/NyCKizP/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 35 bytes

```powershell
filter f{if($_.Rank){$_|f}else{$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCsIwDIbve4oQKrRQZc6bIOzo2avIGJrisOjsJipbn722nRvaQ5v835e0vj3JNGfS2jlV6ZYMqK5SnBWLXXm9iI4VvbKkG/KVtS7nCfgjec6XqcxSuUqFhKmcYMAikt8MtxUKOVKPQyD/nZxnaXAGNwpZXOV/iN0Y/c3g/hDscIe1/h2aREAPM@iizEpjyrcERq@aji2dYAOsGJCh5qHbEESpVzFGxvGLcE53nCZRrMcZTKz7AA)

[Rank](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays) - Returns the number of dimensions in the array. Rank = `0` if an object is not array.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ΔvyD1«Āië`}})
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JSyShfDQ6uPNGQeXp1QW6v5/390tKGBjpGBTrQxEJsYxMbqmBrE6oBEY0GUkkemEowLoqONQLIQURAJ1AoRV4qOBQmByNhYAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X9oVVmlvZLCo7ZJCkr2lf/PTSmrdDE8tPpIQ@bh1Qm1tZr/a3X@R0cbGugYGehEGwOxiUFsrI6pQayOAkg4FkwreWQqxepA@GCBaCOgAqgwiATqhkooRceCxEBkbCwA)

Not the easiest challenge in 05AB1E, since the merge builtin for lists is also used for strings, so reducing by concatenation like most other golfing languages are using isn't possible. Also, flattening one level down with `` €` ``  will also flatten down strings to a list of characters (and push them in reversed order), otherwise `` Δí€` ``  would have been a 4 byter:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JTDax81rUn4/z862tBAx8hAJ9oYiE0MYmN1TA1idUCisSBKySNTCcYF0dFGIFmIKIgEaoWIK0XHgoRAZGwsAA) or [see the incorrect output of all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X9oVVmlvZLCo7ZJCkr2lf/PTTm89lHTmoT/tTr/o6MNDXSMDHSijYHYxCA2VsfUIFZHASQcC6aVPDKVYnUgfLBAtBFQAVQYRAJ1QyWUomNBYiAyNhYA).

```python
Δ          # Loop until the result no longer changes:
           # (which will use the implicit input-list in the first iteration)
 vy        #  Foreach over the items:
   D       #   Duplicate the current item
    1«     #   Append a "1" to each inner-most string/integer
      Ā    #   Truthify each inner-most string
           #   (we use the appended "1" so every string/integer - even "", "00",
           #   0, 000, etc. - becomes truthy)
       i   #   If this is truthy (will be falsey for lists of truthy values):
           #    (use the duplicated item as is)
       ë   #   Else (it's a list instead):
        `  #    Pop the list, and push all its items to the stack
       }   #   Close the if-statement
 }         #  After the foreach-loop:
  )        #  Wrap all values on the stack into a list
           # (after which the resulting flattened list is output implicitly)
```

With builtins, we could of course have used the single byte flatten builtin `˜`:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//9Jz//6OjDQ10jAx0oo2B2MQgNlbH1CBWByQaC6KUPDKVYFwQHW0EkoWIgkigVoi4UnQsSAhExsYCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X9oVVmlvZLCo7ZJCkr2lf9Pz/mv8z862tBAx8hAJ9oYiE0MYmN1TA1idRRAwrFgWskjUylWB8IHC0QbARVAhUEkUDdUQik6FiQGImNjAQ).

Interesting enough, the incorrect result of the 4-byter could have been 1 byte as well with the flattened characters builtin `S`:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@P//6GhDAx0jA51oYyA2MYiN1TE1iNUBicaCKCWPTCUYF0RHG4FkIaIgEqgVIq4UHQsSApGxsQA) or [see all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X9oVVmlvZLCo7ZJCkr2lf@D/@v8j442NNAxMtCJNgZiE4PYWB1Tg1gdBZBwLJhW8shUitWB8MEC0UZABVBhEAnUDZVQio4FiYHI2FgA).